# Can I send my new book to many publishers at the same time?

Tags: publishing

Can I send my new book to many publishers at the same time? If I did what will happen if two of them accepted the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read their submission guidelines, not only for this but for many other details.

In particular, many will decree, No simultaneous submissions.  This is because they do not want to get caught having put in the effort to decide to buy a work, and discover they lost it to another publishing house.

Comment: Interesting. I've never even heard of a publisher that demands no simultaneous submissions before today. Where I'm from (small market) it's accepted that authors submit to more than one publisher and the ones that get a bidding war going are considered extra lucky. Reading up on this in English though seems to suggest bidding wars aren't even on the radar (quoting a backside of simultaneous submissions being to have to withdraw the piece from other publishers...) Although maybe it differs between novels and articles.